# sphinx js:function directive doesn't recognise params

Tags: javascript, parameters, python-sphinx

I get the following error using the js:function directive. Why doesn't :param recognise multiple values between ::?

"
invalid option data: extension option field name may not contain multiple words.

```
.. js:function:: f(test,test2)  
   :param test:  
   :param test2:
```

"

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a blank line between the directive and its options.